# Tracking both raw materials and finished goods inventory

Tags: bookkeeping

Generally the period I am interested in in tracking my business is monthly. So when I buy raw materials in quantities that are going to last me more than one month, I book them to a current asset account for raw materials inventory (I actually have several of these accounts for each raw material).

Then, when I close out a month, one of the tasks is to do a transfer from the raw material inventory to a COGS expense.

Now my business has grown to the point that finished goods inventory really needs to be tracked.

So from a modeling perspective what is the best way to do that? One way I can think of is to transfer all of the raw material $ that were used in production that month to the finished goods account. Then transfer what was sold that month from finished goods to the COGS account. This would have the effect leaving the excess production in finished goods so I would see what remains.

And then a related question: given the approach above, the value of my finished goods inventory will be equal to its COGS cost. How do I add extra so that I can see the market value? From what account would that magic extra value come?